# Configure Selenium Nodes without a JSON file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-server

I am using Amazon Web Services to host a Selenium Hub and Selenium Nodes.

I launch the `hub` like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -port 4444;
```

And I launch the `nodes` like this:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.1.119:4444/grid/register
```

This gives me a configuration like this:
[image: CONFIG]

As you can see, this configuration for the node contains `Firefox` capability and `MaxInstances` is set to 5.

How can I change this so that `Firefox` is NOT allowed (but Chrome is) and change the `MaxInstances` to 2 without using a JSONconfiguration file. I am using `UserData`, so I am not able to use an external file, I can only script it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When launching nodes:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.1.119:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=2,version=latest,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver
```